# Which is correct; will not wake up early or would not wake up early?

Tags: word-choice, conditional-constructions, auxiliary-verbs

> 1. If today is Sunday, then vinoth will not wake up early.
> 2. If today is Sunday, then vinoth would not wake up early.

Which one of the above is correct?

Can I use would not for above sentence?

Comment: Neither of those are correct because we do not start proper nouns with lower-case letters. _If today is Sunday, then VInoth will be getting up late._

Answer (score 1):

Usually when using conditionals you need to perform a tense shift.

> Today **is** Sunday, Vinoth **will** not wake up early.
>
> If today **was** Sunday, Vinoth **would** not wake up early.

Comment: Nice. still not clear about tense shift. Do you mean to say if i use conditionals, then instead of using present tense we have to use past tense. Like instead of using is and will, we should use was and would

Comment: This is not correct.  The first sentence is wrong because that's a [comma splice](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/commasplice.htm) - you can't just ram together two clauses with a comma like that.  For the second one, [if you really want to be correct about it, you have to say "If today **were** Sunday, Vinoth would not wake up early."](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/subjunctive-verbs)  If you want to use "is", though, then it would be correct to say "If today **is** Sunday, then Vinoth will not wake up early."

Answer (score 0):

These are [conditionals.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-and-wishes/conditionals-if)

The proper way to make the first conditional is

> If today **is** Sunday, Vinoth **will** not wake up early.

The proper way to make the second conditional is

> If today **were** Sunday, Vinoth **would** not wake up early.

This is an interesting example, because I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you probably know whether or not today is Sunday when you say this. If today is **not** Sunday, then it is perfectly normal to use the second conditional (since the "if" condition can't possibly be true).

If today **is** Sunday, then it would be more usual to not use a conditional at all:

> Today is Sunday, so Vinoth will not wake up early.

You might put it in first conditional for ironic or humorous effect, though, I suppose.